# Google sign up pop-up does not appear for choosing accounts

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-signin

I have made a google sign up button using the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)

However, on execution, the pop-up window that usually appears for choosing a google account does not appear.

I have added an onClick option on the google sign-in button and used the function googleSignUp().

Below, I have put code I have used

```
package com.example.testapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mp;
    int index = R.drawable.picture1_1;

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(currentUser);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//will hide the title
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); //hide the title bar
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        SignInButton signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);

        final ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);

        final int resId[] = {R.drawable.picture1_1, R.drawable.picture1_2, R.drawable.picture2_1, R.drawable.picture2_2, R.drawable.picture3_1, R.drawable.picture3_2, R.drawable.picture4_1, R.drawable.picture4_2, R.drawable.picture5_1, R.drawable.picture5_2, R.drawable.picture6_1, R.drawable.picture6_2, R.drawable.picture7_1, R.drawable.picture7_2, R.drawable.picture8_1, R.drawable.picture8_2, R.drawable.picture9_1, R.drawable.picture9_2, R.drawable.picture10_1, R.drawable.picture10_2};

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Random rand = new Random();
                        index = rand.nextInt((resId.length- 1)  + 1);

                        imageView.setImageResource(resId[index]);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 300000, 300000);

    }
    public void Clicked(View view){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Hello User",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mp.start();
    }

    public void googleSignUp(View view) {

        GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
            // a listener.
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            updateGUI(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Log.w("null", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
            updateGUI(null);
        }
    }

    private void updateGUI(Object o) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"SignUP by google Successful?",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser account) {
        if(account==null)
            Toast.makeText(this,"NULL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(this,"SignUP Successful?",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

I am getting no errors but the code does not give the desired result.

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication with Google, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).

Answer (score 0):

In the official documentation example:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/8262596a009b50b6c99191001f7e5470391bcc4a/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/java/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L71-L75

The code that declares and configures the GoogleSignInOptions is in the `onCreate()` method rather than in the class like your example shows. Perhaps instead of

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // you declared it here

    public void onCreate() {
        // rather than here
    }
}
```

try putting it in the onCreate method

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onCreate() {
        // declare and build it here
        
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: On doing that, the gso variable becomes accessible in only the onCreate method and nowhere else. I have to use it in googleSignUp method too